# maven+tycho: change build folder for "eclipse-application" target from "eclipse" to something

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, tycho

I build my Eclipse RCP application with Maven 3 + Tycho plugin.
the build output structure is:

```
/target
  /win32.win32.x86 
      /eclipse
  /win32.win32.x86_64
      /eclipse
  /linux.gtk.x86_64
      /eclipse
  /linux.gtk.x86
      /eclipse
  /product-1.0.0.13-linux.gtk.x86.zip
  /product-1.0.0.13-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip
  /product-1.0.0.13-win32.win32.x86.zip
  /product-1.0.0.13-win32.win32.x86_64.zip
```

product**.zip files have "eclipse" top folders in them.

How can I change the build so that the top level folders be called "myproduct" instead of "eclipse"?

Comment: this is impossible with Tycho 0.10 because "eclipse" folder name is hardcoded in it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is still "hardcoded" (if it ever was) but when it comes to being selective about what you want/how you want things in your archive, I've always found the [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin to be a great help in renaming/deleting/rezipping; you'll just want to disable the default packaging plugin for the projects that use this as there is no point in packaging twice.